# Why cannot find -lole32,-luuid TDM-GCC64 + Go + GTK?

Tags: c, go, gtk, mingw

I am trying to create a user interface in Go with GTK, after installing everything as follows:

1. https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/
2. Fix -Wl errors
3. Install TDM-GCC-64

After all these steps, I run "go run main.go" and I get the following response:

```
# github.com/mattn/go-gtk/glib
In file included from glib.go:5,
                 from _cgo_export.c:4:
..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\mattn\go-gtk@v0.0.0-20191030024613-af2e013261f5\glib/glib.go.h:183:1: warning: 'GThreadFunctions' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  183 | static void _g_thread_init(GThreadFunctions *vtable) {
      | ^~~~~~
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:111,
                 from ..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\mattn\go-gtk@v0.0.0-20191030024613-af2e013261f5\glib/glib.go.h:4,
                 from glib.go:5,
                 from _cgo_export.c:4:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/glib/deprecated/gthread.h:56:8: note: declared here
   56 | struct _GThreadFunctions
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# github.com/mattn/go-gtk/glib
In file included from ..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\mattn\go-gtk@v0.0.0-20191030024613-af2e013261f5\glib\glib.go:5:
..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\mattn\go-gtk@v0.0.0-20191030024613-af2e013261f5\glib/glib.go.h:183:1: warning: 'GThreadFunctions' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  183 | static void _g_thread_init(GThreadFunctions *vtable) {
      | ^~~~~~
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:111,
                 from ..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\mattn\go-gtk@v0.0.0-20191030024613-af2e013261f5\glib/glib.go.h:4,
                 from ..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\mattn\go-gtk@v0.0.0-20191030024613-af2e013261f5\glib\glib.go:5:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/glib/deprecated/gthread.h:56:8: note: declared here
   56 | struct _GThreadFunctions
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cgo-gcc-prolog: In function '_cgo_1efdb3e50950_Cfunc__g_thread_init':
cgo-gcc-prolog:192:3: warning: 'GThreadFunctions' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:111,
                 from ..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\mattn\go-gtk@v0.0.0-20191030024613-af2e013261f5\glib/glib.go.h:4,
                 from ..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\mattn\go-gtk@v0.0.0-20191030024613-af2e013261f5\glib\glib.go:5:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/glib/deprecated/gthread.h:56:8: note: declared here
   56 | struct _GThreadFunctions
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# github.com/mattn/go-gtk/gdk
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lole32,-luuid
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Where is that comma coming from in `-lole32,-luuid`?

Comment: This message is displayed by VSCODE on execution. Thank you for your response. :)

Comment: @OsKaR `-lole32,-luuid` should be `-lole32` and `-luuid` as 2 seperate linker flags. You need to find out where this libraries are specified and why they are treated as one argument with a comma in the middle.

Comment: Follow this tutorial: [link](https://www.programmersought.com/article/40724486840/) , if I remove the comma no error comes out, but when I run the console stays frozen.